# How to port relational database definition to Kotlin exposed API?

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, database-design, kotlin-exposed

I'm migrating a database to PostgreSQL using the Kotlin exposed library. It is made in MongoDB Atlas and structure for an entry of `User` is:

```json
{
  // a property
  "login": "login123",

  // array of objects
  "userItems": [
    {
       "example": "value!"
    },
    {
       "example": "value!"
    }
  ]
}
```

Similar to this data class in Kotlin:

```kotlin
data class User(
  val login: String,
  val items: List<ExampleObject>
)

data class ExampleObject(val example: String)
```

How to port this to the new database definitions? `User` doesn't have a field `items` in its data class so must be a non-relational table. `ExampleObject` goes to its own non-relational table, separate from `User`. How can I establish reference between them? How can I retrieve all `userItems`(`ExampleItem`) for a user? Should `ExampleUser` hold a field `relatedUserId` or is this relation done in database?

I defined table `Users` like:

```kotlin
object Users : Table() {
    val id = integer("id").autoIncrement()
    val login = varchar(name = "login", length = 50)

    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id)
}
```

How should `ExampleObject` table look? What must `CRUD` function to create `ExampleObject` have in its arguments?